# How to syntax highlight text which is not already highlighted?

Tags: font-lock

I'd like to highlight function calls in C code, eg:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
 `((,(concat
   "\\([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*\\)"       ; Object identifier
   "\\s *"                              ; Optional white space
   "(")                                 ; Paren for method invocation
   1 'font-lock-function-name-face t)))
```

However this will highlight `switch (`, `if (`, `while (` ... etc. as well as text in comments.

Besides explicitly excluding all keywords in the regex above, is there a way to only highlight text which does not already have any highlighting applied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can tell font-lock to apply some syntax highlighting only if the matched text is not already highlighted by font-lock.

To do this, you use **`keep`** for `OVERRIDE` in the match expression:

`(MATCHER SUBEXP FACESPEC [OVERRIDE [LAXMATCH]])`

See the Elisp manual, node [Search-based Fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html).  There you will see `OVERRIDE` described this way:

> If `OVERRIDE` is `t`, this element can override
>   existing fontification made by previous elements of
>   `font-lock-keywords`.
>
> *If it is **`keep`**, then each character is
>   fontified if it has not been fontified already by some other
>   element.*
>
> If it is `prepend`, the face specified by `FACESPEC` is
>   added to the beginning of the `font-lock-face` property.
>
> If it is `append`, the face is added to the end of the `font-lock-face`
>   property.

Comment: Works! solution:  ``(font-lock-add-keywords c-mode `((,(concat "\\([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*\\)" "\\s *" "(") 1 'font-lock-function-name-face keep))))``